# Why is AWS CodeDeploy giving me an AccessDeniedException from an account with administrator privileges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cli

I'm trying to create a deployment group in AWS from the CLI and I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateDeploymentGroup
operation: User: <redacted> is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on 
resource: arn:aws:codedeploy:us-east-1:<redacted>:<redacted>
```

The user account I'm doing this from has the AdministratorAccess permission, so I'm stumped as to why the account isn't authorized to do this. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going wrong: I wasn't properly specifying a service role. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html) for how to do this. Once you create a service role with the needed permissions, you then need to get that role's ARN in order to reference it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup "Trust relationships" so that CodeDeploy has the privelege to assume the role.

In this link start with step 8 and review your configuration.

[CodeDeploy Trust relationships](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html)